# Warn new users who ran into a question ban on other sites before they post here on Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, post-ban, warning

I propose that new users who recently ran into a ban from asking questions anywhere else on the network be shown a warning before asking a question here on Meta Stack Exchange.

A huge portion of those questions are either users asking about their ban (who should ask on their per-site meta instead) or asking their low-quality question here and trying to get an answer *here*. There's a very small chance of it being a legitimate case where a new user wants to post a question here on Meta Stack Exchange if they're question-banned on any other site in the network.  The majority of the time, posts from new, banned users are either blatantly off-topic, off-topic because they're about one specific site, or a duplicate of [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

A warning telling users that they probably shouldn't be posting here would likely reduce the total number of off-topic questions asked here (both blatantly off-topic and site-specific).

An **example** of such a notice would be:

> ### Wait!
>
> We noticed that you're not currently able to ask questions on [site]. Please read the following information carefully before posting here:
>
> - **If you wish to ask about your ban:** Please carefully read our [guidance for banned users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). If you have a further question that was not answered in that post, please post your question on the **per-site meta** of the site you're banned on.
> - **Please make sure your question is on-topic for this site.** This site, Meta Stack Exchange, is not the right place to post a question that you intended to post on a different site because you're banned from that site. If you post your question here, it will be closed as off-topic.

**Update:** As per gnat's comment, it's possible to tell whether or not a user has attempted to ask a question once a ban is in place. As such, I'm changing this request to something more technically feasible.

Comment: I suspect that question banned users on other sites will often not have the reputation necessary to post on their per-site meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153414/reputation-requirements-for-posting-on-meta-stack-exchange-and-per-site-metas

Comment: This would be incredibly difficult if not *impossible* to implement. Question block status is not recorded on a user's profile anywhere, and cannot be propogated to the network account. It's calculated on the fly when a user attempts to post, which means there's no way to know *here* if a user is blocked somewhere else without doing a *lot* of work looking at every site where they're a member.

Comment: @animuson So then how does the system know, if someone tries to migrate a question to a site where the author is blocked from posting questions, or suspended?

Comment: @PolyGeo Even a post-banned user can suggest two approved edits to get past that restriction.

Comment: @Sonic It doesn't. The system actually attempts to perform the migration, and once it's in the other site's space, when it attempts to connect the user, it instantly rejects the migration if that user is blocked. That's why a "migration rejected" stub appears in the revision history after such an event.

Comment: @animuson [No, it does not.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261324/2157772).

Comment: Interesting that it only locks and unlocks. But the process is still the same. It doesn't know the status on the other site until it's actually trying to create the post on the other site.

Comment: "Even a post-banned user can suggest two approved edits to get past that restriction." but not if they are not engaged enough to learn about that, and I think you are talking about quite new users in your question.

Comment: strongly related: [Let's help askers who are trying to circumvent question block at Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260)

Comment: see also: [People get lost and crash into meta - maybe we need roadblocks for their safety](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306329/165773)

Comment: I downvoted, see my answer as to why. This question comes across as being hostile to new users, and I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: @JohnDuffield wonder if you have seen how such questions are handled here. Last 10 I've seen ended up with score between -6 and -15 and were closed in a matter of few minutes. I somehow doubt that warning new users that they are in danger of breaking their noses like that is really hostile

Comment: @gnat : where are they? Can you give me a hyperlink?

Comment: @JohnDuffield these are all deleted, I have links in my flag history (that's why I can find out score, title and closed status) but content can be seen only by users with 10k reputation

Comment: @gnat : am I misunderstanding something here? I've been sitting looking at the list of Meta Stack Exchange questions, and I can't see any new questions coming in.

Comment: yes you are misunderstanding @JohnDuffield - questions I mention are visible on a site for only a brief time (that's why I asked if you have seen these). After getting heavily voted down and closed these tend to be quickly deleted

Comment: @gnat : I'll leave a window open for a while to keep an eye on the new questions.

Comment: @gnat : is it a slow day?

Comment: hardly slow, more like a usual one. i think I observe 1-2 such questions a day. Since I visit this site rather infrequently, maybe I miss some and there are more but not much, like 3-5 a day - I think I'd notice if there were more than that

Comment: @gnat : like rene said, that's not a massive problem then.

Comment: @JohnDuffield that may be so, I am not much interested in diving into these matters - I merely was surprised with your point about hostility as you could see in my comment above, "I somehow doubt that warning new users that they are in danger of breaking their noses like that is really hostile"

Comment: @gnat : OK noted.

Comment: while comment from @animuson about "incredible difficulty" is technically correct, it is also very easy to address if you [edit] the proposal and replace warning criteria of "banned from asking" with very similar but much more practical "who recently bumped into question block". Information about cases when user actually hit the block is kept in the system and is rather easy to obtain, as evidenced eg by answers to [this statistics request](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6592/31260) at SE.SE meta. As a side note you can request similar stats for MSE

Comment: Incidentally, I have recently posted another question which touches on the fact that the rejection migration is not shown in revision history/timeline - as mentioned in the above comments. Here is link to the question: [Information about migration rejected because of post-ban/suspension?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309286)

Comment: @animuson but moderators can see if a user is question banned, so it is recorded somewhere. No?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No it's not. It's just calculated whenever a moderator views their profile.

Comment: @animuson Is gnat's comment above true?

Comment: @SonicWizard We do store the datetime that the user last hit the block. But we still don't propagate that information to a network level that would make it accessible on other sites. But either way, it's already been decided we wouldn't implement this kind of warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users are shown a warning before they receive a question ban. If it didn't help then, it won't help here either. Developer time is better invested into something that improves the quality of the content that lasts, not on dealing with rejects.

Comment: Developer time is better invested into something that improves the overall quality of content that gets posted here on Meta.

Comment: Precisely this. Just about anyone hitting a ban has already been swaddled in yards of silky-soft warnings and guidance, which they've probably never read. Giving them more text to read - after first running an expensive cross-site lookup - isn't likely to make one bit of difference.

Answer (score -9):

> Warn new users question-banned on other sites before they post here on Meta

Warn them of what?

> I propose that new users who are banned from asking questions anywhere else on the network be shown a warning before asking a question here on Meta Stack Exchange.

I really don't like the idea of *new users* being banned from asking questions. Yesterday there was a question about new users being on the receiving end of close votes, and how it upsets them. I think it's a bad idea for Stack Exchange to permit/foster actions that upset/alienate new users. A warning here will only exacerbate that.

> A huge portion of those questions are either users asking about their ban (who should ask on their per-site meta instead) or asking their low-quality question here and trying to get an answer here.

Then maybe there's a huge problem.

> There's a very small chance of it being a legitimate case where a new user wants to post a question here on Meta Stack Exchange if they're question-banned on any other site in the network.

That's a sweeping statement. This feels like it's heading towards a global warning everywhere saying *new users are not welcome*.

> A warning telling users that they probably shouldn't be posting here would likely reduce the total number of off-topic questions asked here (both blatantly off-topic and site-specific).

Like bro said, it won't help. It will just make new users who feel aggrieved feel even more aggrieved.

Comment: I guess you aren't aware of the massive problem of users posting blatantly off-topic questions (e.g. programming questions) here on MSE. An SE employee said in an answer that half of those posting such questions here are banned on their respective sites.

Comment: @Sonic Wizard : no I'm not. I've looked at the questions, I can't see a massive problem. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @SonicWizard it is not a *massive* problem. We have enough people around to get rid of it in due time. It might survive for a couple of hours but there are still enough hands/voters available to get it moderated even without staff around. It only becomes a problem if we can't handle it anymore on our own.

Comment: I'm afraid you missed the point of this question... some examples on off-topic questions posted on Meta SE: [want-to-update-the-digits-phone-with-mobile-no-in-wp-usermeta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309256/),  [cross-compile-paho-mqtt-c-library-for-arm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309223/), [why-not-work-set-image-resource-on-adapter-class-in-override-method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309222/). Despite being deleted, you can see the title slug on the address bar which indicates that these are off-topic and won't be received well on here either.

Comment: @HTTPS : I saw the phone question. I haven't missed the point of this question. What's come out is that it isn't a massive problem. See my conversation with gnat above. But regardless of that, I reiterate my point that it's a bad idea for Stack Exchange to permit/foster actions that upset/alienate new users.