# If a user is banned from posting answers, state so before they start writing the answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, post-ban

Answer-banned users aren't informed they can't post an answer before they try to post an answer (which typically happens after they write an answer). They're only notified when they've finished their answer and try to submit it.

Can users who can't post answers please be notified of their ban beforehand?

Comment: It's calc'd OTF each time there's a need to know; the status isn't stored in a variable on the Profile. Sources: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1007747_309220  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1007752_309220 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1008668_309220 - Can chng b4 posting

Comment: To expand off Rob's comment: because they are calculated on the fly, it is also an expensive thing to check. Running that check every single time a user loads a question page is not viable at all. Only running it when someone attempts to post an answer reduces resource load.

Comment: Wow, this discussion on whether or not this is a duplicate and for what reason... was getting long. If people still wonder whether they should or shouldn't close vote, the discussion is [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1583/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-an), and you can continue discussing it there.

Comment: @animuson how come you can do this with question bans?

Comment: @PlaceReporter99 in his comment animuson states "running that check every single time a user loads a question page" is expensive, and the check would ideally happen at that point because questions have an answer box so people could start typing an answer. In contrast, the question ban should be checked only when somebody actually clicks the Ask Question button, which happens much less often than visiting a question page.

Comment: However @animuson it may be possible to do this more cheaply and still warn users earlier, for example check for an answer ban the first time a draft is saved (after 45 seconds)? Then banned users don't risk to lose a large amount of work. A separate issue of course is whether SE wants to accomodate banned users at all, I have also read the argument somewhere (in the context of question bans) that banned users are a lost cause and it's fine if they stay banned forever.

Answer (score 1):

[Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob) and [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) mention that the reason not to state before they start writing the answer that the user is not authorized to post an answer is technical: the authorization is calculated on the fly and is expensive to check, consequently it doesn't make sense to check it all the time since most users are authorized to post answers.

Details from the comment section:

> - It's calc'd OTF each time there's a need to know; the status isn't stored in a variable on the Profile. Sources: [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1007747_309220) [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1007752_309220) [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1008668_309220) - Can chng b4 posting – [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob) [15 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214462_363950)
> - To expand off Rob's comment: because they are calculated on the fly, it is also an expensive thing to check. Running that check every single time a user loads a question page is not viable at all. Only running it when someone attempts to post an answer reduces resource load. – [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)**[♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)** [15 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214464_363950)
> - Similar cross-site duplicates, which offer insights into the mechanism: [meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318202/3648282](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318202/3648282) [meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323194/3648282](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323194/3648282) - you can have a warning or message, but until you actually push the button you don't know the *true* answer. The permission to post can change a moment later, any message prior to actually pushing the button would be an estimate of what you should expect the result to be; and not the actual result. – [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob) [4 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214520_363950)

Comment: That's true for IP bans, especially since one can be imposed while one's on a question page, or un-imposed during that time as well. However, answer bans can be known in advance, just like question bans, and question bans have the warning in both places (before writing *and* on submission), so there's no reason why not to have the warning in advance.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thx good point!

Comment: How come they can do it on question bans?

Comment: @PlaceReporter99 it's not accurate, the message says you're *close to being banned*.