# Power-tripping mods?

Tags: discussion, moderators

**Read before you decide THIS question is off-topic**

I don't expext to get much sympathy on this one but....

I posted my question on serverfault thinking it was for networking questions. Gets put on hold as off-topic, my mistake, no big deal, let's move on. (Also I didn't get notified of either hold or response to my subsequent flag for migrate. Not sure about flags but I know holds are supposed to show)

- Flag my question to be moved to site holding mod suggested it be moved to: denied with no explanation
- I politely ask for a suggestion as to where to move and the reply? "Frankly, this is a terrible question.  I won't put it anywhere else."

You could imagine 4 hours for such a helpful response and I was a bit peeved.  I had a specific question about a specific function of a uniquitous networking device and he was telling me, rather rudely, that it didn't belong anywhere on the ENTIRE stack network.  Didn't offer a single word as to why it was so terrible.  I illustrate, in kind, how that's not so helpful and question gets closed as "too many off-topic comments."  There were **two** comments by me: one about the relevant site and the other about the complaint (which was the only one he deletes, doesn't like being questioned I guess)

Just so my post can have a specific question

- I've heard of power-tripping mods here and was wondering just how bad it is.  I haven't had any other issues but I want to avoid it as much as possible.
- I probably know who it was (no names) because of how the question was closed, but is there a specific way to know who responded to a flag request?  Again just to help avoid future situations.
- Funny enough person who closed put another question of mine on hold yesterday, but I agreed it was too broad and deleted it.

**Relevance of THIS post:**
If you think discussing moderator behaviour is not a meta topic we can have a separate debate on that.  If you think this belongs on meta.serverfault: this post wasn't about the specific question posted there - it was was about a moderator's behaviour and the context isn't specific to serverfault.  Also I'm new there and can't post to meta.

Comment: Comments purged. Remember, rule #1 is be honest, rule #2 is be nice. If you can't do both, there are other places on the 'Net.

Comment: as far as I understand you _can_ post on meta. [This recently introduced feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274518/165773) provides ability to post on meta of the site you asked your question no matter how new you are or low is the reputation. @Shog9 could you please check maybe this feature wasn't turned on at SF or maybe there was something else that could block the asker?

Comment: It's enabled on SF @gnat.