# Why can't I start answering questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I just registered and I want to start answering questions. Why won't it let me? It just says I have to earn 5 reputation. But I just want to answer questions right now, not ask questions.

Comment: You realize you are on Meta here? Maybe not Super User? There is at the moment a high flood of off-topic questions coming in from across the network. To counter this flood the minimum rep level needed was raised.

Comment: @rene there is a chance that particular [recent tweak over here gone wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278683/statistics-regarding-users-who-recently-flooded-mse-with-blatantly-off-topic-deb#comment902510_278683). Temporarily elevated rep limit was supposed to be for _asking_ and not for _answering_

Comment: @Jason what site exactly? Where exactly did you register and what question you want to answer and can't?

Comment: @gnat that is why I'm commenting as I do, thanks for the link.

Comment: Hi Jason, on _which_ site do you want to answer questions?

Comment: @Tim this one (MSE) is the only site where he "just registered", any chance what you did caused users with 1 rep to not be able to post answers as well?

Comment: I just clicked questions and it was about egg.js (in the javascript section) and it wouldnt let me answer. I want to be able to contribute as well as answer questions, I have no questions at the moment. I just know its in bad taste to ask all the time without giving. The instructions on this site are always unclear.

Comment: The actual reason is explained by Shog [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278689/152859). In short, it's very temporary, and will be removed in couple of days anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278689/295232), your problem should be solved now. If you really intend to answer a question here, you should be able to do it now.

Comment: where do i mark this as solved? its unclear, sorry...

Comment: If you mean the [tag:status-resolved] tag, that one can only be used by moderators.

Comment: Somebody just edited my question for grammar mistakes and I got points taken away. Is it really that crucial?If it is, I think the rules need to be more visible for newcomers to see. lets be real, most newcomers aren't looking that deep into the rules(especially about grammar). That's a little unexpected.

Comment: @Jason no points were taken away from you. You have 2 upvotes  on the question worth 10 points, and 2 points for accepting this answer, making it total of 13 points you now have, as you start with 1. Answering (and asking) requires 2 points, you can do both now.

Comment: Would you rather have somebody NOT edit your gramatical mistakes and somebody just down vote your question because of those preventable grammatical mistakes?  Stop being so obsessed with reputation.  Reputation means less here but grammatical mistakes on SO is not good