# Should we update the TOS post with a banner to point clueless users at SO for their programming questions?

Tags: discussion, new-users, off-topic, low-quality-posts, announcements

Ever since the [TOS update](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa), Meta Stack Exchange keeps getting flooded by ridiculous questions (mostly about general programming and code, but occasionally for other sites than SO) whenever the privilege of posting is briefly restored to 1-rep users. [Not many of those users were evading q-bans on SO](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278683/statistics-regarding-users-who-recently-flooded-mse-with-blatantly-off-topic-deb) when last checked, so the current working theory is that that pesky inbox notification is still bringing in hordes of users even two months later.

If they're *looking at that*, though, perhaps we can stick a banner at the top and/or the bottom of the MSE post itself* to tell them to buzz off? Something polite, like this:

> **Note**: If you just remembered an important programming question you need to ask, don't ask it here — [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is the place for you! Meta Stack Exchange is only for questions and answers about the Stack Exchange network as a whole.

*Sticking it in the post body has the advantage of being more immediately noticeable than elsewhere, since, presumably, they're trying to read that post.

Comment: technically similar proposal in a bit different context: [Let's help askers who are trying to circumvent question block at Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260) - "how about showing them a warning...This hopefully would help them avoid further frustration if they get down and close votes, angry comments..."

Comment: @soup: I'm aware, but I'm hoping catching them before they read the thing they came here for may improve matters.

Comment: FWIW [current plan](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278688/users-with-1-rep-cant-view-any-questions-here-on-mse/278689#comment910715_278689) seems to be to _"just mark all remaining inbox messages "read" for this little event and call it done"_

Comment: Frankly I wasn't sure what you meant by that, but on first reading, I thought "we" was referring to Stack Overflow, then on second reading I was trying to guess if you meant some other site (Programmers.SE?), before deciding neither of those made sense.  I've edited to clarify in case there's anyone else who had the same confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Although I agree this is a problem that needs fixing. I have asked before why this wasn't just a blog item, which would have solved the issue.

However, I don't really think this is a solution that will help anything. As [soup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/315433/soup) commented:

> a site-wide banner was tried already and didn't seem to help. The people who post programming questions here are locked in write-only mode.

They don't read anything you tell them to. The questions are usually awfully formatted, full of spelling and grammar mistakes, and lacking everything that could help anyone to give an answer.

There users are just stubborn. They want to solution, no matter what. Placing a banner won't fix that.

Comment: The blog post would certainly **have been** far better. But it's too late for that.

Comment: Oh yes. Certainly.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278562/245360