# Where can I ask a question related to a specific computer game?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to ask something about a really old game. I want to know if it was continued or anything was made on the same storyline in the past years. Where could I ask this kind of question? I tried to ask the question on Arqade, but it was closed as off-topic so I guess that was the wrong one.

You can see the original question here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291079/is-there-a-sequel-or-spinoff-to-jurassic-wars

Comment: Is it a video game? Then [gaming.se] is the right spot. If it's not on-topic there, then it's not on-topic anywhere else in Stack Exchange. I suspect your question was probably closed for a different reason.

Comment: I edited my question and posted a link with the original one. My question is simply about a game's sequel if it exists or not, that's it.

Comment: Then this is something you need to bring up on [Meta Arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com).

Comment: But my question started there and it was put on hold for "off-topic"

Comment: The question does seem to be objectively answerable, actually...  @AʟE. OP only has 1 point on Arqade, so they can't post on Meta Arqade.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Granted, but the community at Arqade are the only ones who can _really_ explain why the question was closed. Not to mention the [recent change which allows people without enough reputation to generally ask a question on a per-site meta _can_ ask about their specific question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277727/21960).

Answer (score 7):

If it was marked as off topic on <s>Gaming</s> Arqade then there's nowhere on the network where it would be on topic.

There are plenty of questions that, for one reason or another, aren't suitable for the Stack Exchange question and answer model. There are other places on the internet where you can ask such questions.