# What happens to new users with less than 5 rep when their questions are migrated to meta?

Tags: discussion, migration, per-site-meta

Yesterday on [Retrocomputing](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com) a new user asked a question which I believed was off-topic on main but on-topic for Meta.  I voted to migrate the question, and a few hours later it was [moved by a moderator](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/418/621).

What I didn't realize at the time was that new users need 5 rep to participate in Meta.  What happens in this particular case?  The user's question moved to meta, but are they unable to participate (answer or comment)?

Comment: looks like it is possible but I'm not sure if this also works if their question is migrated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274518/a-way-for-new-users-to-ask-about-their-post-specifically

Comment: I suggest two options.  The first is no fiddling with the SE infrastructure.  Someone just grants the guy four more rep.  He is obviously not a spammer, and he asked an intelligent question worth an up-vote anyway. The second would take a minor tweak to infrastructure.  His question has in fact been up-voted on meta.retro.  Allow such meta up-votes to raise rep up to the 5-point threshold.

Comment: This is entirely anecdotal, but I've seen (IIRC) questions from < 5 rep users migrated where said user did comment and participate on the question. However, I more often see the question migrated and the user never come back to it.

Comment: @Kendra I have no idea what actually occurs.  I just know how it is documented on the [rep page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges): *5 -- participate in meta -- Discuss the site itself: bugs, feedback, and governance* // I do not even know what "participate" entails. Can't access page? Can read but not ask new questions, make answers, make comments? Or something else?

Comment: @RichF Well, there's a way to see what a user without the rep would see... Hit the meta site without logging in. You can still read the meta posts, you just can't comment, edit, ask a new question, answer a question, vote...

Comment: So, found an example. [At least on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343262/where-can-i-submit-my-c-program) (and I can't see why it'd be different for the other sites) a user with < 5 rep can indeed interact with their post after it is migrated to meta. Not posting as an answer because I have no way to verify that this is the case for other metas, and I know Stack Overflow _sometimes_ gets special rules...

Comment: @Kendra plus your linked question only illustrates that he could comment directly to his own question.  Could he comment to answers of his question? Could he learn something and provide an answer? (rhetorical unless someone already knows) My main point is, the poor guy deserves at least 4 more rep. 

Answer (score 7):

Users can interact with their own questions.  [Here is an example from Mi Yodeya meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3655/472); notice that the OP commented on one of the answers.

I believe the "need 5 rep for meta" check is made at the time that a user tries to post.  It's clearly not server-side because questions from 1-rep users *can* be migrated, and it appears that it's not specially checked for other interactions once the question is on meta.

The same situation also applies for all of one's prior posts on a site's meta, not just migrations. If a user had enough reputation to post on meta and then lost rep, that user can still interact with the existing posts.