# Is this the right place to ask questions about how to use Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, meta

And if not, where? Specifically I want to know how to re-ask a protected question.

It was not my question, and it was protected because it had received low-quality answers that had had to be deleted.

Comment: The right place would be to inform yourself from any specific site's Tour and Help Center first. If your question was closed, the reasons why, are specifically stated in the appearing banner. If you reask be sure your question will meet the quality policies of that specific site.

Comment: But is this the right place to ask questions about asking questions about Stack Exchange?

Comment: Ask on that site's meta.  You can find the link to that site's meta by going to the site, then clicking on the "stackexchange" dropdown in the header.

Comment: the closed question was not my question, and the listed reason it was closed was because it had received low-quality answers that had had to be deleted.

Comment: Questions aren't closed because of its answers; are you sure it wasn't "locked" or "protected"? (Both of which are different from being closed)... anyway you should ask about *specific* questions on that site's meta (or here if the question is on this site).

Comment: You should never "re-ask" an existing question, that's called, asking a duplicate question.  If you can make it clear how your question isn't a duplicate then you can ask your question.  Ask this question on the meta website for the SE website the current question is at.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is. However it's more accurate to say it's a great place to **find out how** to use Stack Exchange. Many questions have already been asked.

You can learn more about the closing process in a canonical question called [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question) . In general you do not "re-ask" a closed question. Instead you edit it so that it can be re-opened. More details are at [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question)

A protected question can still be answered (see [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) ) and you don't need to re-ask it. New and low-rep users can't answer it, but everyone else can. If you'd just like to get more eyes on it because you want to know the answer yourself, see [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions) and consider using some of that advice to get this question answered.

If you want site-specifc advice about how to edit a specific question - what to add, what parts to take out - then this overall Meta is not the best place to ask, and you should ask on the meta of the site where your question was closed. But it was right to come here first, since you have now learned you don't re-ask closed questions, and the difference between closed and protected, among other things.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response.

Please know that the closed question was not my question, and the listed reason it was closed was because it had received low-quality answers that had had to be deleted.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

Meta.SE (this site) is the place to ask questions that apply to the network as a whole.  If you have a question about question blocks, the process of closing or reopening questions, or what "primarily opinion-based" means, for example, you can ask here.

If your question is specific to another site, such as "why was this question closed?" or "what do I need to change to get this reopened?", then you need to ask on the meta for your site.  People here can't tell you what close voters on Stack Overflow or Parenting or Webmasters expect from questions.

It's always ok to ask general questions on the per-site metas, so if you're not sure, ask there.  Even if you don't have enough reputation to participate on meta otherwise, you can always ask [specifically about your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274518/162102).

Comment: Alas, I do not have sufficient reputation to ask on think different's meta site.

Comment: @EricR you should be able to ask specifically about your question even if you can't post otherwise.  See my edit.

Comment: The challenge in this case is that it is not my question I am interested in. I have tried asking the site's chat, hopefully that will get me down the road. Thank you!

Comment: @EricR ah, I see.  Yeah, in that case chat is a good place to try.  To understand site-specific issues you really need to reach the users of that site somehow.  Good luck.