# If a new user finds an incorrectly spelled tag where do we report it?

Tags: support, tags, site-specific

As my first question on the site was when the misspelled tag was found No features are active to use meta, edit, or chat.

In this case, should the tag be posted in Meta under "support" "tag" "re-tag"?

Comment: I am sorry if this is incorrectly tagged. feel free to edit to place in correct topic . ( if that is possible)

Comment: @PolyGeo thank you, but that was about multiple tags and the user had the ability to edit tags i believe. I will edit to specify for new users.

Comment: You should always be able to suggest an edit.

Comment: @PolyGeo i will try, but it is not a tag that i used it was a tag that popped up as suggested and was misspelled.

Comment: @PeopleCallMeAdam Hey, me too! =)

Comment: @AdamLear my name isn't Adam though ! lol

Answer (score 1):

It is always worth checking whether the misspelled tag has only been used once (or very few times).  If it has, then just edit or suggest an edit to change it.

Otherwise, I think that you should report it to the Meta of the site on which you noticed the incorrectly spelled tag.

Alternatively, if that site has an active chat room, dropping in there and mentioning it will often achieve the same result more quickly.

Comment: ok, thank you there wee 14 uses of the tag. also I was not a high enough rep rating to participate in their meta. just realized it the first question i asked.

Comment: Perhaps you have 20 rep to participate in their chat room.

Answer (score 0):

Per site meta - as you would a tag that needs to be removed.

The 5 reputation minimum for meta is *not that high* and I'd post the question anyway, (optionally using the mispelled tag) .

*Then*

This is a bit of a cheat *but* you can then post [a meta question about your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274518/a-way-for-new-users-to-ask-about-their-post-specifically), even without the 5 reputation, referencing the fact that you had a mispelled tag suggested in the main question.

Its much better though, to post something worth an upvote before you meta it of course.

Comment: This is embarrassing, good thing the 5 rep limit exists.It is correct, the word has three spellings depending on the meaning, and region it is being used. May i leave the question up on here ? I think it can be of use to future users. I was able to find out how to edit the tags, they are not instantly accepted and have to be reviewed but at least it is a way to do it. you have to click on the (i) or information button while selecting the tag and you can edit or review the tags.

Comment: In theory, the broader problem still theoretically exists - and its certainly unusual, and plausible. Reviewed edits are fine, but you *still* want a meta post before bulk editing.  Getting that 5 reputation points really is a start, no matter where the problem is.

Comment: arahant was the tag. it is in the Buddhism SE other forms are "arhat" and "arihant"

Comment: ooh, Almost certainly needs discussion - though in terms of potential synonyms rather than tag correction/editing. This is why meta discussion is useful for things like this.

Comment: is there a better word to use ? i genuinely ask, because it seems like there are quite a few.

Comment: I have no idea. Amusingly, wouldn't that be something worth fleshing out, then asking on the Buddhism SE?

Comment: _I'd post the question anyway,_ you're a mod on your main site. you don't have to request a mod to correct a typo if you're 100% sure

Comment: Well, I don't consider tags *that* important, and they're certainly something you can edit. And maybe I'm an old timer, but 5 reputation feels trivial on any site I know enough to post about. Also, association reputation isn't enough for edits. I do suggested edits sometimes, and totally occationally grab someone with more rep for trivial edits. Just cause I'm a SU mod doesn't give me super awesome powers everywhere